# Classes from required Eclipse plugins are missing when building with Maven

Tags: maven, tycho

I want to do the simplest Maven build with Tycho, but couldn't get it working. My project has only one pom.xml file, there are no parent or sibling POMs.

When I run `mvn clean install` I get lots of compilation errors which entries such as:

```
[ERROR] /dir/file.java:[8,33] package org.eclipse.core.commands does not exist
```

This is how my POM file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>myartifact</name>
    <description>Maven stuff</description>

    <properties>
        <tycho.version>0.20.0</tycho.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <luna-repo.url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna</luna-repo.url>
        <kepler-repo.url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler</kepler-repo.url>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>luna</id>
            <url>${luna-repo.url}</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>kepler</id>
            <url>${kepler-repo.url}</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pde>true</pde>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is how my manifest file looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: pluginname
Bundle-SymbolicName: pluginname;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Bundle-Activator: com.mygroup.pluginname.ui.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.apache.commons.io;bundle-version="2.0.1"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: .
```

I don't really know what I am missing here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add a dependency for the set of libraries you are using in your source code.

Maven isn't being told to obtain or manage them, so Eclipse doesn't know they exist. When you are trying to import them in your source code and compile, it's generating the error you are seeing.

Ex:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>commands</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0-I20070605-0010</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

See the [eclipse repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.core) for the info required for other libraries.

EDIT: To fix your SWT compilation error, follow the steps shown on the [SWT-repo project's webpage](https://code.google.com/p/swt-repo/). An example for the win32 Intel x86/x64 architecture:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Change yours based on your platform.

Comment: Thanks! Somewhere I remember reading that adding `maven-eclipse-plugin` is all we needed for dependencies. I added all the dependencies however still getting `package org.eclipse.swt.widgets does not exist` errorr. (Note that this is the only compilation error, all the other ones are gone)

Comment: @SarpKaya edited. Note that plugins are used to support execution of the different lifecycle steps, they are not used to resolve compile-time imports.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but what if I want to do it for multi platform?

Comment: @SarpKaya include a dependency for all platforms you want to support. When you package up and distribute your artifact, the dependent jars should also be supplied with it, so anyone on one of your supported platforms can run.

Comment: The OP says "I want to (...) build with Tycho". This solution is not using Tycho but rather describing a potential approach without Tycho.

Answer (score 4):

Your project doesn't specify a packaging type, so it defaults to `jar`. For `jar` projects, Tycho doesn't do anything, so all your otherwise correct configuration has no effect.

To activate Tycho, you need to add the configuration

```
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
```

Then, Tycho will resolve the build class path according to the dependencies you have declared in the OSGi manifest.

---

Note that Tycho doesn't use the `maven-compiler-plugin`, so after activating Tycho this configuration has no effect. Also, I have no experience with the `maven-eclipse-plugin` in combination with Tycho. Instead of that plugin, I would recommend to use [M2Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) for importing the project in Eclipse.